# Can not access deep category and product links - url shortened

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url-rewrite

when I try to access some deep category I am alwyas redirected to link of parent category.

for example
i try access `store.com/category/subcategory/subcategory2/subcategory3/subcategory4`
but i am redirected to
`store.com/category/subcategory/subcategory2/subcategory3`

same with deep product url `store.com/category/subcategory/subcategory2/subcategory3/product`
also redirects to
`store.com/category/subcategory/subcategory2/subcategory3`

i am using nginx server. but i discovered that this redirecting happening in magento, not with server rewrites. can someone point me where should i start search?

i am using CE 1.9.2.1 with few plugins and porto theme

Answer (score 0):

finaly found answer. it is caused by **MKleine_LanguageRoutes** module. when this is disabled, deeper links work again.